# Creating a custom 503 page on Django app

Tags: python, django, apache, custom-error-pages

Below is my apache configuration file for django in the sites-enabled folder. I am trying to use a custom 503 page when the server is down. But, the document root is not honored when using this django config. Also I tried putting it under an alias like /data/my-app-static and using it to generate the page. What is that I am doing wrong ? I also annotated the config with the stuff I am trying to do.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    WSGIDaemonProcess my-app python-path=/data/my-app:/data/my-app-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup my-app
    WSGIScriptAlias / /data/my-app/intel_django/wsgi.py
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    SetEnv my-app_HOME /data/my-app
    SetEnv my-app_STATIC_DIR /data/my-app-static
    SetEnv my-app_MEDIA_DIR /data/my-app-media

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/data/my-app/intel_django">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/media/ "/data/my-app-media"
    Alias /static "/data/my-app-static"


    <Directory "/data/my-app-static">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all

        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/data/my-app-media">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # This line just throws 503 all the time and is being used for testing.
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=503,L]

    # I have a 503.html in /var/www, but doesnt work.
    ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    #SSL Conf
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache/ssl/selfsigned.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache/ssl/selfsigned.key

</VirtualHost>
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Shameless plug; if you're looking for an easy way to put your site in or out of maintenance mode, have a look at: https://github.com/alsoicode/django-maintenancemode-2

Comment: Thanks man. This looks nice. But, this is like running another django app when the site is in maintenance mode right. I was just looking for an easy and dirty way to display a page.

Comment: Actually no. It's your Django app, with some extra middleware to intercept requests, except for admin, or patterns you specifically ignore, that returns a 503 response with the template of your choice. There is a test application in the repo for demonstration purposes, but that doesn't get installed via pip.